# JQuery select for: two attribute's value not equaling each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to do a JQuery select function for elements that have two specific attributes that have different values.

(The reason why is so that i can select inputs that have been changed.)

However, i cannot seem to find any documentation that shows such a scenario.

Here is a test to hide an element that was selected in this way, but like i said, I cannot find the right syntax to make it work.

I have tried:

```
"[value]!=[oldvalue]" 
"[value!=[oldvalue]]" 
"[value!=oldvalue]"
```

And some other crazy things that all fail.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("[value<>[oldvalue]]").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p value="2" oldvalue="1">This is a paragraph to go away.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to hide the `p` if `value` is not equal to `oldvalue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a filter for that as the logic is too complicated for a single selector. Try this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('[value][oldvalue]').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('value') != $(this).attr('oldvalue');
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `data-*` attributes instead of invalid HTML attributes like `value` and `oldvalue` on a `<p>` tag...

Comment: Good point. I assumed that the attributes in the question were just placeholders.

Comment: They were place holders.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the invalid HTML in your example, you would achieve this by using jQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('[value][oldvalue]').filter(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return $el.attr('value') !== $el.attr('oldvalue');
});
```

```js
var results = $('[value][oldvalue]').filter(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  return $el.attr('value') !== $el.attr('oldvalue');
});


$('[value][oldvalue]').hide();
$(results).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p value="1" oldvalue="2">Show me!</p>
<p value="1" oldvalue="1">Do not show me!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could target all elements that share both attributes and then use the jQuery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to find those that don't match :

```
$("button").click(function(){
  // Find all elements that have both attributes
  $('[value][oldvalue]').filter(function(){ 
       // Filter those that do not match
       return $(this).attr('value') !== $(this).attr('oldvalue');
  }).hide();
});
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/vatoxa/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 1):

Guess I posted this at precisely the same time as a slew of other people but I've got a snippet here that works.

Select all the elements with the desired attributes and use `filter()` to reduce the set to those with unequal values like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var els = $("[value][oldvalue]").filter(function(i) {
      return $(this).attr('value') != $(this).attr('oldvalue');
    }).hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p value="2" oldvalue="1">This is a paragraph to go away.</p>
<p value="2" oldvalue="2">This is a paragraph to <b>not</b> go away.</p>

<button>Click me</button>
```